# Como montar o retorno Json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, pdo

Não sei como fazer ou a quem recorrer. Preciso fazer este retorno json com Jquery.Ajax

Gostaria de passar parametros mais ou menos assim

No JAVASCRIPT tenho assim

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../execs/proc_fluxocaixa.php",
            data: {d_acao: "grafico", c_tipo: tipo, c_dia: dia},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(ret_dados){
               var pageviews ret_dados["r_dados"];
            }
        });
```

Meu PHP tenho assim:

```
if($acao == "grafico"){
    $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
    $dias = 30;
    $mes  = 3;

    if ($tipo == 0){
        ///Debito

        $Saida[] = array();
        for($i=1; $i <= $dias; $i++) {
            $dataC = date("Y-$mes-$i");

            $diaSQL = $Sv->selectDB("SELECT SUM(valor) TotalDia FROM mov_contas WHERE tipo = 'D' AND apagado = 0 AND banco = 0 AND data >= '$dataC 00:00:00' AND data <= '$dataC 23:59:59' GROUP BY data");

            if (count($diaSQL) == 0){
                $TotalValDia = 0;
            } else {
                $TotalValDia = $diaSQL[0]["TotalDia"];
            }

            $Saida[] = $i . "," . $TotalValDia;
        }
    }

    $retorno["r_dados"] = $Saida;
}
```

Como faço no PHP e no retorno para ficar assim:

```
            var pageviews = [
                [1, randValue()],
                [2, randValue()],
                [3, 2 + randValue()],
                [4, 3 + randValue()],
                [5, 5 + randValue()],
                [6, 10 + randValue()],
                [7, 15 + randValue()],
                [8, 20 + randValue()],
                [9, 25 + randValue()],
                [10, 30 + randValue()],
                [11, 35 + randValue()],
                [12, 25 + randValue()],
                [13, 15 + randValue()],
                [14, 20 + randValue()],
                [15, 45 + randValue()],
                [16, 50 + randValue()],
                [17, 65 + randValue()],
                [18, 70 + randValue()],
                [19, 85 + randValue()],
                [20, 80 + randValue()],
                [21, 75 + randValue()],
                [22, 80 + randValue()],
                [23, 75 + randValue()],
                [24, 70 + randValue()],
                [25, 65 + randValue()],
                [26, 75 + randValue()],
                [27, 80 + randValue()],
                [28, 85 + randValue()],
                [29, 90 + randValue()],
                [30, 95 + randValue()]
            ];
```

Comment: mostre como vc retorna o array no php, assim fica mais fácil ajudar

Comment: nao analizei muito o seu codigo php, mas vc tem q trocar o `data` do ajax por algo assim: `{"d_acao": "grafico", "c_tipo": tipo, "c_dia": dia},`
Coloque um `console.log(ret_dados)` após o `success` e veja oq retorna

Comment: Ele está retornando 
[Array[0], "1,1850.00", "2,0", "3,0", "4,0", "5,0", "6,0", "7,0", "8,0", "9,0", "10,0", "11,0", "12,0", "13,0", "14,0", "15,0", "16,0", "17,0", "18,0", "19,0", "20,0", "21,0", "22,0", "23,0", "24,0", "25,0", "26,0", "27,0", "28,0", "29,0", "30,0"]

Comment: Na verdade como seria o correto para coletar estes dados, quero pegar o total do dia na movimentação do caixa para jogar no gráfico, onde o tipo = 0 significa que é débito.

E este formato que passei que preciso é o necessário para gerar o Gráfico

Comment: agr vc so precisa formatar o array de acordo com o plugin de grafico q vc ta usando

Comment: var plot = $.plot($("#chart_2"), [{
                    data: mov_debito,
                    label: "Sa&iacute;das",
                    lines: {
                        lineWidth: 1,
                    },
                    shadowSize: 0
                }

precisa ser assim
                var mov_debito = [
                    [1, randValue()],
                    [2, randValue()],
                    [3, 2 + randValue()],
                    [4, 3 + randValue()]
                ];

Comment: Olha só:
        var mov_debito = "";
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../execs/proc_fluxocaixa.php",
            data: {d_acao: "grafico", c_tipo: 0},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(ret_dados){
                mov_debito = ret_dados["r_dados"];
                console.log(mov_debito);
            }
        });         

        alert(mov_debito);

No console aparece a formatação correta e no alert esta vazio, tipo não alimentou a variavel